# Treat particular folder as actual folder not as controller CodeIgniter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I want to make a particular folder to be treated as an actual one, not as a controller in codeigniter and also want to redirect my all domain.com requests to www.domain.com. I have the following htaccess code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond $1 !^(FOLDER_TO_BE_EXCLUDED)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Redirect non-www to www:
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L] 

</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

If I uncomment the lines (Redirect non-www to www), all requests are treated as controller
so the folder (FOLDER_TO_BE_EXCLUDED) is also treated as controller. I want to access this folder as an actual one.

If I will not redirect non-www to www I cant access session variables on inner pages.

Hope you will understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RewriteCond only apply to the RewriteRule which follows: your rules (commented now) were incorrect.

Besides, IMO, the simplest way to define exceptions like this one, is to use a non-rewriting rule like: `RewriteRule ^FOLDER_TO_BE_EXCLUDED/ - [L]` (on "top" of rewrite rules)

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect non-www to www:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$0 [R=permanent,L]

RewriteRule ^FOLDER_TO_BE_EXCLUDED/ - [L]

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?url=$0 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `RewriteCond` to your last RewriteRule:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(folder_name/)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]
```

This should stop it redirecting www.yourdomain.com/folder_name to the index.php.

You can add more folders to the condition using the `|` character:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(folder_name/|another_folder/)
```